# Problem related to the transfer function of RC low pass filter

Tags: low-pass, laplace-transform, passive-filter

I have the following question:

> For the passive RC low pass filter shown below:
>   $$V_S(t)=\cos(t)+\cos(100t)$$
>   $$V_0(t)=\alpha\cos(t+\theta)+\beta\cos(100t+\phi)$$
>
> (where \$\alpha\$, \$\beta\$, \$\theta\$ and \$\phi\$ are constants)
>
> [image]
>
> The value of \$\displaystyle \left|\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right|\$ is?
>
> The answer is \$10\$

I have tried using the transfer function of a RC low pass filter :

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{sRC+1}=\frac{10}{s+10}$$

$$\implies h(t)=10e^{-10t}u(t)$$

Then tried using the two given equation with \$h(t)\$ as below:

$$h(t)=\frac{V_0(t)}{V_S(t)}$$

After that I am stuck. Even after trying with Initial value theorem as \$h(0)=\lim_{s \to \infty}sH(s)\$, I end up with :

$$\alpha\cos(\theta)+\beta\cos(\phi)=20$$

Can someone please tell if I am missing something or if the question doesn't provide enough information?

Comment: why not superposition. determine the gain and phase change per sinus stimulus. Hint. Replace s with jw and replace w with the freq of interest

Comment: @JonRB still how would I eliminate \$\phi\$ and \$\theta\$?

Comment: you don't :)  thats what you are after.

Comment: @JonRB I don't understand. How can I get the ratio \$\displaystyle \left|\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right|\$ without eliminating them?

Comment: by determinig them

Comment: @JonRB Can you explain a bit more on this `why not superposition. determine the gain and phase change per sinus stimulus. `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85006/discussion-between-paulplusx-and-jonrb).

Comment: @JonRB Could you please look into the chat(final two messages in the chat) and let me know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @JonRB Thank you so much. It was really simple but I didn't understand you at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer function of this circuit is: 
$$H(i\omega)=\frac{10}{10-i\omega}$$

Insert w=1 and w=100 into the transfer function: 
$$H(\omega=1)=\frac{10}{10-i}$$
$$H(\omega=100)=\frac{10}{10-100i}$$

Build the absolute ratio of both transfer functions:
$$\displaystyle \left|\frac{H(w=1)}{H(w=100)}\right|$$
$$= \displaystyle \left|\frac{10}{10-i}*\frac{10-100i}{10}\right|$$
$$= \displaystyle \left|\frac{10-100i}{10-i}\right|$$
$$= \displaystyle \left|10*\frac{1-10i}{10-i}\right|$$
$$= 10$$

Comment: Thank you for the verification. I did it in the same way (if you look in the chat).